# Why does UITapGestureRecognizer not work properly for cell images in Swift collection view?

Tags: swift, uiimage, cell, uitapgesturerecognizer, uitouch

I have added **UITapGestureRecognizer** for collectionview cell image like

code: with this code if i tap on two cell images then both are showing. Here if i tap on second cell image then how to remove first image from foreground

here `touchesBegan` not calling when i tap on outside of the newImageView(but on collectionview) why? is there any solution for this

[o/p screen of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC3uk.jpg)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: FriendCollectionViewCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! FriendCollectionViewCell

let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(cellTappedMethod(_:)))
cell.profileImageView?.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()
cell.profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
cell.profileImageView.tag = indexPath.row
cell.profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)


return cell

}

@objc func cellTappedMethod(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){

let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
newImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width * 0.7, height: 300.0)//UIScreen.main.bounds
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) { [self] in
    
    newImageView.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.center.x - 15, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.center.y - 200)
    
    newImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    
    self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
}
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{

let touch = touches.first
print("touch..outside")

var sender = UITapGestureRecognizer()
print(sender.view?.tag)

if ((touch?.view) != nil){
    print("touch..")
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
}



@objc func dismissFullscreenImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) { [self] in
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
}
```

if i tap on cell image then how to remove all image which are in foreground. please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired behavior of removing the previous image from the foreground when tapping on a new cell image, you can keep track of the currently displayed image view and remove it before adding a new one.

```
var currentImageView: UIImageView?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: FriendCollectionViewCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! FriendCollectionViewCell
    
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(cellTappedMethod(_:)))
    cell.profileImageView?.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()
    cell.profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.profileImageView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    
    return cell
}

@objc func cellTappedMethod(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
    
    currentImageView?.removeFromSuperview()
    
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
    newImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width * 0.7, height: 300.0)
    newImageView.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.center.x - 15, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.center.y - 200)
    newImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
    currentImageView = newImageView
}

@objc func dismissFullscreenImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
    currentImageView = nil
}
```

In this code the `currentImageView` variable is declared at the class level to keep track of the image view currently displayed on the screen. When a cell image is tapped, the previous image view (if any) is removed from the superview before adding a new one. The `currentImageView` variable is updated with the new image view, and when dismissing the full-screen image, the reference is cleared to indicate that no image view is currently displayed.

As for the issue with `touchesBegan` not being called when tapping outside the `newImageView`, it's because the `newImageView` is on top of the collection view and intercepts the touch events. One solution is to subclass `UICollectionView` and override the `touchesBegan` method in the subclass.

```
class MyCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, existing image remove issue fixed but instead of `class MyCollectionView: UIViewController` i cant use `class MyCollectionView: UICollectionView` bcz it leads to so many other issues